# Running SQL script in Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mariadb, containers

I want to run an sql file with ddl and dml when I'm creating a MariaDB database with docker. I have specified the file in my root directory in my docker-compose file like this.

```
volumes:                                                   
  - "./scripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
```

However, when I run the docker-compose up command, it only creates the databases without tables and data, how exactly should I fill the database.
I couldn't find any helpful sources for this.

*Edit*
I tried it with a small sql file, containing only this ddl, and still nothing was created.

```
CREATE TABLE `ALARM_A` (
                                  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                                  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                  `creation_date` datetime NOT NULL,
                                  `is_new` bit(1) NOT NULL,
                                  `order_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
                                  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

*Second edit*
I have changed my docker-compose a little bit, and now it creates the tables, however, it is done partially, instead of 59 tables I got 3.
I tried deleting containers and creating again, as well as building again, but I get the same result, here is my docker-compose file.

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  phedon-service:
    build: .
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - phedon
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    env_file:
      - .env
  mysql:
      image: mariadb:10.6
      container_name: mariadb
      volumes:
        - container-volume:/var/lib/mysql
        - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: name_db
      ports:
        - "3307:3307"
networks:
   phedon:
volumes:
  container-volume:
```

*UPDATE*

I added this in the db service part

```
volumes:
      - container-volume:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
```

And this at the bottom of my compose file

```
volumes:
  container-volume:
```

Make sure to delete your volumes before you run the docker build command, and afterwards you can compose perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `init.sql`? This seems to work just fine for me when I try it.

Comment: The file is too big, around 2 GB, so I can't really show it here. Should I maybe specify a maximum size for it?

Comment: Create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the problem you're asking about.

Comment: Just edited the post, still got no results

Comment: can you post the dockerfile and compose file?

Comment: If your application/framework has a native migration/seed-data system, I'd just use that, the same way you would with a non-Docker database.  If that's not an option, can you [edit] the question to include a complete example; what's in the `docker-compose.yml` file, and what commands exactly are you running?

Comment: my dockerfile has not details about the db, only the service, I just posted the docker-compose which is responsible for the db

Answer (score 1):

If I have your example SQL script in `scripts/init.sql`, and I use this `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10
    volumes:
      - "./scripts/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
    environment:
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MARIADB_DATABASE: example
```

Then after I `docker-compose up` and wait for initialization to complete, I see:

```bash
$ docker-compose exec mariadb mysql -psecret example -e "show tables"
+-------------------+
| Tables_in_example |
+-------------------+
| ALARM_A           |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: The same thing didn't work for me, you can see the new edit I just posted.